# In Java, is it possible to validate user input with both a alpha and numerical value?

Tags: java

The example is I want the employee to enter there employee ID. The ID has the following format ANN-NNN.
"A" being a letter and "N" being a number. I want to validate the entry to have an alpha for the first space and 0-9 digit thereafter. I know how to validate alpha and how to validate int but not in the same input by digit. Any ideas? This is how I'm validating the letter in the first space entered:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter letters:");
while (!sc.hasNext("[A-Za-z]+")) {
    System.out.println("Nope, that's not it!");
    sc.next();
}
String word = sc.next();
System.out.println("Thank you! Got " + word);
```

Comment: Try this `sc.hasNext("[A-Za-z][0-9]{2}[-][0-9]{3}")`;

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `next()` instead of `nextLine()` here?

Answer (score 0):

As amihelpful commented, change your regex to this:

```
sc.hasNext("[A-Za-z][0-9]{2}[-][0-9]{3}")
```

This essentially means "any A to Z char upper or lower, followed by 0-9 {2} times, followed by hyphen, followed by 0 to 9 {3} times. There are many ways to do this, but I'd say you might consider in general when working with regexes:

- if you're expecting the regex to cover the entire input, start it with ^ and end with $
- using predefined character classes may make things neater

Hence you could say this:

```
sc.hasNext("^[A-Za-z]\\d\\d-\\d\\d\\d$")
```

Not using ^ and $ could get you into trouble sometimes as if the user enters an invalid string that contains a valid one, the regex match will still pass, e.g. AA11-2222 would match by the first regex above but not the second.

Whether you think \d is clearer to read than [0-9] is a personal thing, but I use c# a lot which allows us to declare strings with an @"like this \d" so we don't need to escape every \ and I find this more readable

I further recommend you change your prompt text because it tells the user to enter letters only. And I recommend you make your error message more informative. A good error message tells the user what went wrong and what they can do to fix it on their own. If you ever work a support desk after uni you'll wish that this mantra was followed more often, when you're saying for the hundredth time today "error 99 means you didn't fill in a last name"

Comment: Worked! Thank you so much!